# Entity Framework select with join and id

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Simple question, but no luck with Google so far.

How do I turn this:

```
select * from Products 
left join ProductCategory on Products.ProductCode = ProductCategory.ProductCode
where ProductCategory.CategoryID = 1
```

into a query in Entity Framework Core?

This is what I have and isn't correct:

```
_context.Products
    .Where(p => p.ProductCategory.CategoryID == CategoryID)
    .ToList();
```

Thanks!

**Edit**

When I add an `Include`:

```
_context.Products
    .Include(p => p.ProductCategory)
    .Where(p => p.ProductCategory.CategoryID == CategoryID)
    .ToList();
```

I get this error in the image:
[image]

There is a CategoryID on ProductCategory, but it's trying to find one on the collection?

Comment: Learn to debug.  It's part of programmer's job.  It's obvious that you don't have a column called `CategoryID`.  We don't know the exact names of your columns and tables.  But isn't it obvious???  Replace it with the correct name, maybe `category_id`???

Comment: @Eric - For clarity I didn't want to include uppercase with quotes since that is required for Postgres. I can update the table column names in my question, but that is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: @Eric - you are not quite correct here. It is not the column name. It is the fact that this is a collection of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Include()` LINQ option - [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data). It is used for loading related data.

I'm not familiar with the exact names of your classes and properties, so treat this as a pseudo code, but it should look something like this:

```
_context.products.Include("Product_Categories")
                 .Where(p => p.product_category.category_id == category_id)
```

**EDIT**

It will be a lot easier if you post your classes, so that I can see the relations.

But I assume that your `Product` class has a list of `ProductCategory` and you want to get all the products, that have a specific category. Extending the approach that you already have, you need:

```
_context.products
.Include(p => p.product_category)
.Where(p => p.ProductCategory.Any(pc => pc.category_id == category_id))
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my question. Mind having a look?

Comment: @RickJolly - check the edited answer, and please, if it still doesn't work, post your classes structure (or at least the relevant part). It will help in investigating further problems.

Comment: Thank you. That query would work, but the generated SQL is using the table name `Product` instead of `Products`. Any idea why?

Comment: What is the name of your table, and what is the name of your entity, and what is the name of the object in your DB context?

Comment: Ack, I found the error. I had accidentally given the `ProductCategory` table a type of `Product` in the context file. Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: You don't need include unless you want the collection populated in products coming out of final results.